# Pretty Url not working on the server

Tags: htaccess

I have a wordpress website however I am not able to make the pretty permalinks work on it. 
The htaccess fil is writable on the server with file permissions 777.

So kidly guide me on the issues and how can I fix it.
Here's the code for .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you please put your code here of .htaccess.

Comment: Is it Apache? Is `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled? Wordpress is in the root directory or subdirectory?

Comment: Check similar questions e.g. [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167449/permalinks-not-working-htaccess-is-writable).

Comment: this is not code issues but its server issues please check it is your server is not shared server it is dedicated server so you need to config your self okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dedicated server then you must follow the below steps to run with .htacess

first of note that you need to create a configuration file for each site on your server using FTP.

as below

> /etc/apache2/sites-available

go above path and then create file with below formate

e.g.

```
domain_name.domain_extension.conf

{ hello.com.conf }
```

add below code into it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin serveradmin@etc.com
    ServerName hello.com
    ServerAlias www.hello.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html  # your site data path
    <Directory "/var/www/html"> # your site data path
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All  
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory> 
    ErrorLog /dev/null
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  # to check your log 
</VirtualHost>
```

after setup it.

please switch your permalink two-time vice versa and update your link in WordPress database.

and check I hope its working.

If not working, please restart apache server then.

Comment: OK let me check it once as it is dedicated server

Comment: Yes, check to update me. and other this is your .htaccess is not working now. you can check using redirect URL code e.g 301 code

Comment: The important part here is the `AllowOverride All` (and `Options FollowSymLinks`) directives in the appropriate `<Directory>` container. (You should avoid using line-end comments as Apache does not support them.)